# No network when executing saveInBackground in didReceiveRemoteNotification method

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have enabled "Remote Notifications" background mode and I am successfully handling silent notifications in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" method.

I also need to complete a "saveInBackground" operation after receiving the silent notification while the app is inactive, but it seems that it is not possible to do a network operation in "didReceiveRemoteNotification" when app is inactive. I also tried to make a REST call but also no use.

Is it possible to do a network operation after receiving a silent notification while the app is inactive ?

Comment: What error are you getting? Are you starting a background task during your network operation?

Comment: @JesseRusak when app is inactive, error code from Parse is 100, no network. But when the app is foreground I can send a REST call successfully. No I am not starting a background task during network operation but Parse's saveInBackground should be doing it for me.